# How to load FileReader result into HTML5 video for best compatibility across browsers & devices

Tags: html, video, safari, mobile-safari, filereader

I'm trying to load the selected video file into a html5  for the user to preview the video before sending it to the server.

The problem is that it that using browsers Chrome and Safari on desktop & mobile (ios12), it only works on Chrome for desktop.

Note that once I send this file to my server (saved with CarrierWave and uploaded to S3), and then update the video with the new src url, it works on all browsers & devices.

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = (e) => {
  this.$scope.$applyAsync(() => {
    this.filePreview = e.target.result;
  })
}
```

```html
<video class="video-previewer" ng-if="$ctrl.filePreview" width="{{$ctrl.width}}" height="{{$ctrl.height}}" controls playsinline preload="metadata">
  <source ng-src="{{$ctrl.filePreview + '#t=0.5'}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The error I am seeing in the safari logs on desktop & mobile is the base64 string ("data:video/mp4;base64,...etc...") being logged and "Failed to load resource: Data URL decoding failed"

Why does the decoding fail? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just not using `FileReader` for video, and just using `URL.createObjectURL(file)` directly on the file and it is working.

```
onFileUpload({ file }) {
  const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  const vid = document.getElementById('#id-for-video-preview-element');
  vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  vid.load();
}
```

Comment: Good point about skipping `FileReader`. I've now had a chance to test... +1 for solving it.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Try replacing

```
this.filePreview = e.target.result;
```

With this

```
this.filePreview = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
```

**Option 2:**

You could try an alternate method to load video into a dynamic video tag and see if that works on all HTML5 browsers...

Testable code (dynamically create/destory `<video>` tag as needed) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p> Choose a video file...</p>
<input type="file" id="fileChooser" accept="*/*"/>

<div>
<a id="aTag"> </a>
</div>

<script>

document.getElementById('fileChooser').addEventListener('change', onFileSelected, false);

function onFileSelected(evt) 
{
    var file = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    var type = file.type;
    //alert("file TYPE is : " + type);

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    var tmpElement; //will container the video content....
    var path; //will hold URL of file BLOB (is not file path)....

    reader.onloadend = function(evt) 
    {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
        {
            //# update file path...
            path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);

            //# remove any other existing media element...
            var container = document.getElementById("aTag");

            if (container.hasChildNodes()) 
            { container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]); }

            if ( type == "video/mp4" )
            {
                tmpElement = document.createElement( "video");
                tmpElement.setAttribute("controls", "true" );
                tmpElement.setAttribute("width", "800");
            }
            else
            { return 0; } //break out / cancel

            //# add newly created HTML5 element with file path
            tmpElement.setAttribute("src", path);
            container.appendChild(tmpElement);
        }
    };

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think your solution would work but i ended up coming across a simpler way before your post. Doesn't look like the `FileReader` is completely needed here? I have just implemented my answer and deployed it and is working with s3 on desktop & mobile.